# Links on social media follow buttons wont work

Tags: html, css, facebook, button, twitter

I am using three following buttons for the social media pages, Facebook, Twitter and Google+. The only problem is that the link to follow on the Facebook and Twitter buttons doesn't work, the Google+ works but the two other one doesn't, by link I mean the buttons, where you can see follower/like count and then when you click it as a user it follows/likes the page without you having to go on the page, but the buttons wont work, the "link mouse hover" wont even show up(when you hover over the link and the mouse icon changes from an arrow to a hand).

I have taken the code straight from the development kits provided by Facebook and Twitter. Important note, I am using css to move the buttons, but if I chose to not use css to move them and just keep them the random place they are placed at as default, then the links work, so I think there might be a problem there.

I have removed the links for the follow pages, but the linking should still work as it is "href" so don't mind that.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


        <div id="header">
        </div>

        <div id="container">

        <div id="content">

        </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">

        <div class="twitterTextForButton">
            Twitter
        </div>

        <div class="twitter-follow">
            <a class="twitter-follow-button"
            href="https://twitter.com/"
            data-show-count="true"
            data-lang="en"
            data-show-screen-name="false">
            Follow 
            </a>
        </div>

            <script>window.twttr=(function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],t=window.twttr||{};if(d.getElementById(id))return t;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);t._e=[];t.ready=function(f){t._e.push(f);};return t;}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"));</script>


        <div class="facebookTextForButton">
            Facebook
        </div>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://test.com" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

        <div class="googlePlusTextForButton">
            Google+
        </div>

        <div class="moveGooglePLogo">
        <div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-height="20" data-href="//plus.google.com/test" data-rel="author"></div>
        </div>

        </div>

        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

css code:

```
    .fb-like {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: 35px;
        bottom: -50px;
    }

    .twitter-follow{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: 180px;
        bottom: 126px;
    }

    .moveGooglePLogo{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: 325px;
        bottom: 126px;
    }

.facebookTextForButton{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.twitterTextForButton{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 180px;
}

.googlePlusTextForButton{
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 325px;
}
```

Comment: There is a bunch of absolute positioning happening above. It is plausible that it is affecting the links assigned to your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

for Google+ you need a correct URL. And you have to sort your items.

```
 data-href="https://plus.google.com/+LarryPage"
```

The Facebook-API requires HTTP Server (see [Like button not showing (except jsfiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856560/like-button-not-showing-except-jsfiddle))

You can also use the iframe solution of the Facebook-Button.

Example for your Buttons:

http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMicrochip/djtbg68x/

**---- Update ----**

Do you have used the right links?

**Facebook:** 
http://facebook.com/YOURUSER

**Twitter:** 
http://twitter.com/YOURUSER or http//twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=YOURUSER

Do you have a link where I can try the problem?

Hope that helps.

Greetings

Comment: The Google+ button works and I am able to see all the buttons, because I am already running on a local host, the problem is that the linking and liking/following wont work.

Comment: Ah ok. Do you have used the correct URL's? http://facebook.com/youuser and twitter.com/YOURUSER or https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=YOURUSER ---- I realized my share buttons with share count with some snippets from [Custom Share Buttons](http://danielsetzermann.com/webdesign/custom-social-media-buttons-for-wordpress-with-share-count/), probably that helps.